# Save sheets as pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have this problem trying to print multiple sheets in a single pdf. Browsing online and in the forum i found this code but when i use it i get the ERROR 9 "Subscript out of range" and I don't understand why. I tried in a new workbook the code and it works properly. Can someone help me?

```
Private Sub cmd_PrintPDF_Click()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Costs", "Cars")).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "Cost&Car", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

This macro runs from the main panel of my workbook, where there are various Command buttons that direct you in requested sheets.When i run this macro the sheet "Cars" is hidden, may be is this the problem? I tried with an .Activate before the code but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code for export sheets to pdf. Maybe will be useful for you.

```
Sub SheetsToPdf()

Dim Arr() As String
Dim PdfFileName As String
PdfFileName = "Cost&Car"

ReDim Arr(1, 1)
'sheets name in 1st column, 2nd column for info about visibility sheets
Arr(0, 0) = "Costs"
Arr(1, 0) = "Cars"

Cells(1, 1).Select
For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)

Arr(i, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr(i, 0)).visible ' info about visibility sheets

If Arr(i, 1) = "0" Then 'check visible Sheets "-1" - visible = True, "0" - visible = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr(i, 0)).visible = True
    OrgVisible = False
End If

If i = 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr(i, 0)).Select
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr(i, 0)).Select False 'select all sheets with names in arr()
End If  



Next i

'select all data
Cells.Select

'export to pdf
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
ThisWorkbook.path & "/" & PdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

'restore old visibility for sheets
For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)
    If Arr(i, 1) = "0" Then 'set old visible
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr(i, 0)).visible = False
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Maybe this simpler version you need? Exports only visible sheets:

```
Sub SheetsToPdf2()

Dim PdfFileName As String
PdfFileName = "Cost&Car"

Cells(1, 1).Select
For Each Sheets_ In Sheets
    If Sheets_.visible Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets_.Name).Select False
    End If
Next
'select all data in one sheet
Cells.Select

'export to pdf
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
ThisWorkbook.path & "/" & PdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm pretty surprised by your use of select, I didn't know that we can add a Boolean like this... Thx for teaching me something! ;)

Comment: using 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Costs", "Cars")).ExportAsFixedFormat (...)' i got error '438 - Object doesn't support this property or method' i must try something else :)

Comment: The code works, but it exports also the other visible sheets and not only the "Cars" and "Costs". I have some check boxes that indicate which sheets has to be exported and using an if on the checkbox.Value i make them visible.

Comment: @Magnicco: i edit my answer, export all visible sheets, something like this you need?

Comment: @Dawid The first version was better :) . I have the problem that it prints also the current visible sheet and not only "Cars" and "Costs". I try to explain it in other words. I have a main sheet called "MAIN" where i can mark some check boxes and chose the sheets that i want save as pdf (not only "Costs" and "Cars" but also other 15 sheets if i want"). And your code save in the pdf also the "MAIN" sheet. In addition i dont understand why it prints the sheets in the wrong orfer starting from the last selected.

Comment: @Magnicco: ok, now i understand. Problem is in this line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr(i, 0)).Select False 'select all sheets with names in arr()`. Little modification would be resolve problem (im edit anwser)

Comment: @Dawid with this code i get an error#1004 on the line    Cells.Select

Comment: @Magnicco: very strange, this error should occurs when you select cells and dont select sheets. I try reproduce this error but without results. After loop any sheet are selected?

Comment: @Dawid After the loop are selected some cells in teh 2 sheets ( the ones where was the mouse). Eliminating the new If loop the code works.

Comment: @Magnicco: try move `Cells.Select` to if: If i = 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr(i, 0)).Select
**Cells.Select**
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr(i, 0)).Select False 'select all sheets with names in arr()
End If
Next i

Comment: @Magnicco: im stack :) try remove this line and check results. Maybe change this line to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr(i, 0)).Cells.Select` help?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can't print an hidden sheet
And here is your code without the useless and ressource-greedy `Select` :

```
Private Sub cmd_PrintPDF_Click()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Costs").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Visible = True

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Costs", "Cars")).ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "Cost&Car", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Costs").Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Using your code now i get the error#1004 "unable to set the Visible properties of the Sheets Class". I tried to activate the Sheets before the command but it doesn't work. As i explained before i have a main sheet where, using check boxes, you can activate and edit other sheets. Normally those sheets are all hidden and you can see only the main one.

Comment: I tryed your suggestion but on "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Equipments_to_lube", "Lube_oil_data")).ExportAsFixedFormat " i get the error#438 " Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Are you sure that you can use arrays in sheets?? I've never seen that before your post, so I don't know... But try to separate it in two pieces rather that using an array (or use a loop).

Comment: I used with the code suggested by Dawid in the other comments and it works. May be  Dawid code doesn't use arrays? 
How can i know if i can use array in sheets? Sorry I am really newbie on vba and it's my first code, be patient :)

Comment: ok I have tried to create a new workbook really simple with the 2 sheets and the code doesn't works. So probably I can't use arrays in my sheets. How Can I activate them?